# Attempted to call an undefined method named "createQueryBuilder"

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to understand how to do a QueryBuilder in a service so here is what i've done :

Create my service :

```
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\PurgerAdvert;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class PurgerAdvert
{

    private  $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->entityManager = $em;

    }

    public function purge($days)
    {

$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('a')->from('OCPlatformBundle:Advert', 'a');

// get the Query from the QueryBuilder here ...
$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $result = $query->getResult();
    }   

}
```

Declare it in services.yml :

```
  oc_platform.purger.advert:
      class: OC\PlatformBundle\PurgerAdvert\PurgerAdvert
      arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

I remove the query because i've an error before that : `"Attempted to call an undefined method named "createQueryBuilder" of class "OC\PlatformBundle\PurgerAdvert\PurgerAdvert""` I assume that i didn't call properly the entitymanager but i don't see my mistake ...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just replace `$this->createQueryBuilder()` this `$em->createQueryBuilder()`

Comment: Better if you change `private $entityManager` instead of `private $em` to use then `$this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()`.

Comment: I tried ciurciurek solution but error "Notice: Undefined variable: em" / The solution of gp_sflover is working !! thanks :)

Comment: Just to be sure to understand :
- private $em; // create a private variable to put the entitymanager inside using the construct ?
- $this->entityManager = $em; // create a kind of "variable" called $this->entityManager where we we put the content of $em so we can use it to called method from it ? that's it ?

Comment: You seem to be building up a history of not accepting answers.  Be careful.  Pretty soon your questions will be ignored completely.

Comment: how do i accept a comment as an answer ? the comment of gp_sflover was the one who solved my issue :) (sorry i'm new on stackflow i'll check my other post)

Comment: Hello @Percy Mercy to mark a person's answer as the correct one, click the up arrow; also since you are the poster, click the "check mark" besides the "working" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not want to type `entityManager` all the time, so a combination of both answers should work:

```
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\PurgerAdvert;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class PurgerAdvert
{
    private  $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
      $this->entityManager = $em;
    }

    public function purge($days)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->select('a')->from('OCPlatformBundle:Advert', 'a');

        // get the Query from the QueryBuilder here ...
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        return $result = $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

Try that, I think it should work.

Comment: You forgot `$this->entityManager` :-)

Comment: I messed up my code too @gp_sflover. I edited the code now, so it should be good. Thanks for double checking... ;-)